# waiting for an exception from an Action

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this function:

```
public static async Task<T> Relay<T>(string uriController, T jsonObject)
{
    var json = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        LogHelpers.LogVerbose( "Enter " + uriController );
        using ( var client = new HttpClient() )
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            client.BaseAddress = Uri;
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 20, 0 );
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue( "application/json" ) );
            if ( jsonObject != null )
            {
                var jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( jsonObject );
                var contentPost = new StringContent( jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" );
                response = await client.PostAsync( uriController, contentPost ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            }
            else
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync( uriController, null ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
            LogHelpers.LogVerbose( "Exit " + uriController );
            SendNotification?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

and this is called by:

```
private async void GetPiSystemInfo()
{
    SystemPiInfo = await RaspberryPi.Relay<SystemPiInfo>("Api/SystemPiInfo/IsConnected", null);
}
```

which in turn is run from this:

```
private async Task<bool> RunTheMethod(Action myMethodName)
{
    await Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    myMethodName();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
}
```

Which finally is called from this:

```
 Action[] Actions = new Action[10];

 Actions[0] = GetPiSystemInfo;
 await RunTheMethod(Actions[0]);
```

The reason for this architecture is that when my app starts it will connect to my Raspberry Pi box. Several api calls are made to get the data from that box.

If for any reason connection is not made or an error is returned I wish to rerun the action until it does so (obviously there would be a cut off).

```
Task<T> Relay<T>()
```

Method is generic as it will be called from many different places. So, whenever a server error occurs I would catch and throw back up the stack.

What is happening though is that

```
return true;
```

is being called as soon as the action is called.

Comment: The problem is your `async void GetPiSystemInfo`. You don't await the result, so there is no way to know if an exception ocurred. As you experienced, the method will just return to the calling code as soon as it has to wait for something. Make it an `async Task GetPiSystemInfo` and await the result. This should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I did have that i originally.  But if I put that back in I get an error on this line:

Comment: Actions[0] = GetPiSystemInfo;

Comment: 'Task ApplicationViewModel.GetPiSystemInfo()' has the wrong return type

Comment: Because it returns a `Task` but an `Action` needs to be `void`. Either change your task list (to something that returns a task) or do the synchronization on your own by calling `.Wait` on the result of `RaspberryPi.Relay()` in `GetPiSystemInfo` instead of the `await`. Be aware that this will block the thread.

Comment: yh, i would not want to put .wait on for the reason you state. What can i use to return a task that can be run dynamically?

Comment: You could just make your task list a `Func<Task>[]` instead of `Action[]`. encapsulating a void function in such a structure is much easier than the other way around. Then, you can just await all your actions in your scheduler.